# My Media tags don't work on my website when using my phone

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

I have just uploaded my website and have been having some problems with @media css tags.
On my website on my desktop the scaling works and when i go into inspect and make the resize the page to make it smaller it resizes. The problem is when i go on the website on my phone. It is like the media tags are ignored and it just displays the desktop version of the website.

Here is an example of my code:
I have my meta tags.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is my @media tags. They are below my normal css styles as i know it can be a problem if they are not .

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 400px) {...
```

Here are some pictures of what my website should do when the media tags work.

[Website on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQEII.png)

[Website on Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4OaK.png)

I have tried other tags but they dont seem to work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media query works only when screens are between 100 and 400px. But most of devices are more 400px.(even Iphone XR is at 414px).

Please use this website (https://screensizemap.com/) to check the device dimensions and their popularity and change the media-query accordingly.

But best bet to support all mobiles is use `@media (max-width: 515px)`. Please refer the below image too.

[image: Image showing media groups with highight on mobile media]

Comment: thank you for your answer. It seems to be working now. I was using units that were to small. I set the size to 530px now and it works.